# How do I find the maximum probability using dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, probability

For better understanding of this question, you can check out:-

1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100336/how-to-calculate-the-probability-in-this-case

John is playing a game against a magician.In this game, there are initially 'N' identical boxes in front of him and one of them contains a magic pill ― after eating this pill, he becomes immortal.

He has to determine which box contains the pill. He is allowed to perform at most 'M' moves. In each move, he may do one of the following:

1)

Choose one of the boxes that are in front of him uniformly randomly and guess that this box contains the pill. If the guess is correct, the game ends and he gets the pill. Otherwise, after this guess, the magician adds K empty boxes in front of him in such a way that John cannot determine which boxes were added; the box he guessed also remains in front of him and he cannot distinguish this box from the other boxes in subsequent moves either.

2) Choose a number X such that X is a positive multiple of K, but strictly less than the current number of boxes in front of John. The magician then removes X empty boxes. Of course, John must not perform this move if the current number of boxes is ≤K.

If John plays optimally, what will be the maximum probability of him getting the pill ? 'N' is always less than 'K'.

Example:- Let M=3, so 3 moves are allowed. K=20,N=3.

In his first move, John selects a box with probability, x = 1/3 ,(20 boxes have been added(20+3==23) then in the second move, he again selects a box again, with probability this time, y=1/23*(2/3). Here, 2/3 denotes the probability of failure in the first move.

In the third move, he does the same thing with probability , z = 1/43*(22/23)*(2/3) .

So the total probability is= x+y+z=l1

Lets say, in the above case, in the second move,he chooses to remove 20 boxes and do nothing else, then the new final probability is= 1/3+0(nothing is done in second move!) + 2/3*(1/3)=l2. Now, as l2 > l1 ,so 'l2' is the answer to our question.

Basically, we have to determine which sequence of moves will yield the maximum probability? Also,

P(Winning) =P(Game ending in 1st Move)+P(Game ending in 2nd Move)+P(Game ending in 3rd Move) =(1/3)+0+(2/3)*(1/3) =5/9

Given, N,K,M how can we find out the maximum probability?
Do we have to apply dynamic programming?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let *p*(*N*, *K*, *M*) be John's probability if he plays optimally. We have the following recurrence relations:

- *p*(*N*, *K*, 0) = 0

  - If there are no remaining moves, then he loses.
- if *M* > 0 and *N* < *X*, then *p*(*N*, *K*, *M*) = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>*N*</sub> + <sup>(*N*−1)</sup>/<sub>*N*</sub> · *p*(*N*+*K*, *K*, *M*−1)

  - If there's at least one remaining move, and option #2 is not allowed, then his probability of winning is the probability that he guesses correctly in this round, plus the probability that he guesses wrongly in this round *but* he wins in a later turn.
- if *M* > 0 and *N* ≥ *X*, then *p*(*N*, *K*, *M*) is the greater of these two:

  - <sup>1</sup>/<sub>*N*</sub> + <sup>(*N*−1)</sup>/<sub>*N*</sub> · *p*(*N*+*K*, *K*, *M*−1)

    - If he takes option #1, then this is the same as the case where he was forced to take option #1.
  - *p*(*N* % *K*, *K*, *M*−1), where '%' is the "remainder" or "modulus" operator

    - If he takes option #2, then he certainly won't win in this step, so his probability of winning is equal to the probability that he wins in a later turn.
    - Note that we only need to consider *N* % *K*, because he should certainly choose the largest value of *X* that he's allowed to. There's never any benefit to letting the pool of boxes remain unnecessarily large.

Dynamic programming, or recursion plus memoization, is well-suited to this; you can apply the above recurrence relations directly.

Note that *K* never changes, so you don't need an array dimension for it; and *N* only changes by adding or subtracting integer multiples of *K*, so you're best off using array indices *n* such that *N* = (*N*<sub>0</sub> % *K*) + *nK*.

Additionally, note that *M* decreases by exactly 1 in each turn, so if you're using a dynamic-programming approach and you only want the final probability, then you don't need to retain probabilities for all values of *M*; rather, when building the array for a given value of *M*, you only need to keep the array for *M*−1.

Comment: I am very new to dynamic programming, can you give me the idea on how to write the code for this? + Thanks for all the effort you put in writing these answers, its just huge.

Comment: Is there and O(logM) solution possible ? Like really fast solution. And you said, the greater of both, but how will I know which one is greater? Is there any non-dp solution possible?

Comment: And how will I know the values of 'X' ?